# Program to create a Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone

I am an undergraduate student who is new to programming. Recently my professor wanted me to create a Windows Phone app which should look like a news website (eg: BBC) with any programming language.
The app should work on any WP device, as my professor wanted.
Can someone PLEASE help me with this?
Thanks in advance and finally I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: _my professor wanted me to create a Windows Phone app which should look like a news website_ Please ask him http://whathaveyoutried.com/ `:)`

Comment: @MasterControl Have you looked into app studio? It is app creation ez_mode No real experience required. If that doesn't work then I would crack a book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can to get [Visual studio 2012 or 2013 for windows](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/) **not windows desktop** and second you need to get [windows phone sdk](http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk). That should be it , you'te good to go. If you want to create directx apps you will probably need directx sdk also.

Answer (score 0):

There is a awesome thing called Windows App Studio. No piece of coding and you never want to be part of dev program its free and simple.check this link http://apps.windowsstore.com/ Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can stick with the SDK and develop your app from there, or you can try TouchDevelop that you can develop the apps inside the phone. I tried it back when I had WP7 and it works. https://www.touchdevelop.com/